# activity with two buttons and want to assign different intents

Tags: java, android

i have an activity with two buttons and want to assign different intents for each so they open different activities, can someone help me out with the code in java class on how to specify the intent for the particular widget(button)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do

```
    public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

...
    @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch(view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.redButtonId:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.greenButtonId:
                         Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Activity3.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: life saver thanks man

Comment: also lastly can i also add intents to checkboxes so that when someone checks them boxes, new activity can open up

Comment: For CheckBoxes, it is not the way to do, at least, it is not usual to add such functionality  for checkbox checked listener. But you can do it. Of course. After all, you can decide ultimately. :)

Comment: just to be clear so when someone checks a box a intent that is coded with it can put out a new activity, what would actually be the difference than, wouldn't the code be almost the same except the button ids would be replaced by the ids of check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mButtom.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)`

[View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Or alternatively you can add a single OnClickListener on your Activity and match view with their IDs in the method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // ...
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // ...
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: so if my button1(name is Red) and button 2(name is green) then after specifying the ids how do i assign them specifically that when they are clicked example if red is clicked it goes to activity 2 from main and green goes to activity 3 what would be the intent method then??

Comment: Read the official docs? [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: so in the android:onClick ="abc"
then i need to make an intent
with this 

public void abc(View view){
Intent i = new Intent(this, 2nd java.class);
startActivity(i);
}

would this work

Comment: so i will assign the button 1 with android:onClick ="buttononeonclick" 
and the second one as second and put them inplace of public void buttononeonclick(View view) 

thats the thing i grasp bro? is this okay

Comment: Yes, that should work.